# С : функция возвращает массив символов

Tags: c, строки

**Добрый день:**

Подскажите, как правильно возвращать из функции массив символов?

Я пробую так:

```
/*
    Read user CMD
*/
char* readUserCmd()
//char[50] readUserCmd()
{
    char cmd[50];
    char temp_cmd[50];  

    fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin);

    .......
    return cmd;
}
```

Как правильно я должен сделать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если пишете небольшую, хорошо контролируемую программу, то вполне можете написать `static char cmd[CMD_SIZE];` и безопасно возвращать этот массив (реально возвращаете адрес его первого элемента)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В языке С функция не может непосредственно "возвращать массив". Когда из функции нужно вернуть "массивные" данные, у вас есть несколько обходных вариантов

1. Передавать массив снаружи, а в функции лишь заполнять его

   ```
   void readUserCmd(char cmd[], size_t size)
   {
     fgets(cmd, size, stdin);    
   }

   ...
   char cmd[50];
   readUserCmd(cmd, sizeof cmd);
   ```
2. Создавать массив внутри функции, а наружу возвращать *указатель* на него. Массив при этом придется создавать в динамической памяти

   ```
   #define SIZE 50u

   char *readUserCmd(void)
   {
     char *cmd = malloc(SIZE);
     fgets(cmd, SIZE, stdin);    
     return cmd;
   }

   ...
   char *cmd = readUserCmd();
   ...
   free(cmd);
   ```
3. (Малополезный способ) Завернуть массив в структуру и возвращать её по значению.
4. (Малополезный способ) В способе 2 вместо динамического выделения памяти использовать массив, объявленный внутри функции как `static`.

Answer (score 2):

> Я сделал по Вашему образцу и получил ошибку

Где ошибка:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* readUserCmd()
{
  char* cmd = (char*)malloc(50);
  fgets(cmd, 50, stdin);
  return cmd;
}

int main() {
  char* result = readUserCmd();
  free(result);
}
```

?!

Всё компилируется и запускается.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* readUserCmd()
{
  char* cmd = (char*)malloc(50);
  fgets(cmd, 50, stdin);
  ...
  return cmd;
}

char* result = readUserCmd();
...
free(result);
```

Comment: Я сделал по Вашему образцу и получил ошибку "Error] conflicting types for 'readUserCmd'". Ругается на строку "char* readUserCmd()" !
Это весь код что я должен изменить?
Спасибо

Comment: Вообще-то, это Ваша строчка.